# Range of inverse trigonometric functions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, trigonometry

Let us assume that all numbers are *real*. I'm trying to obtain in mathematica *all* values of `ArcSin` in an interval. In particular, the normal behavior of `ArcSin` in mathematica is that  `ArcSin[x]` is in `[-Pi/2,Pi/2]` interval whenever `x` is real in `[-1,1]` interval.

However, I need to obtain *all* the angles in `[0,2 Pi]` interval for every `x` as above. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
Clear[getAngles];
getAngles[x_, interval : {start_, end_} : {0, 2 Pi}] :=
Module[{y},
  Quiet@Cases[
     Reduce[#, y] & /@ 
       LogicalExpand[
         Reduce[Reduce[Sin[y] == x, y] && start <= y < end, y]], (y == 
     yrhs_?NumericQ) :> yrhs, {2}]]
```

For example:

```
In[90]:= getAngles[0.7]

Out[90]= {0.775397, 2.3662}

In[92]:= {#, Sin[#]} & /@ getAngles[0.7, {0, 4 Pi}]

Out[92]= {{0.775397, 0.7}, {2.3662, 0.7}, {7.05858, 0.7}, {8.64938, 0.7}}
```

Comment: @Simon Sure, I could have used analytical formulas. I guess this reflects my conversion from a physicist to a programmer in recent years.

Comment: OK, I think you understood the OP's question better than I did. Apparently just returning all the values of x, 0 <=x<=2Pi that yield the same y=Sin[x] value.

Comment: @Sjoerd Well, as I understood it, the OP is more concerned with the angles proper than with a particular way you get them, using `ArcSin` (which, as you noted, is impossible), or something else. And as @Simon noted, my way of doing it is an overkill, given that a simple analytical formula exists.

Comment: @Leonid: Your magic seems to be the one I was after. Now I have to correct the follow-up problems. Thanks a lot!
However, what is this simple analytical formula?

Comment: @Dror: For the analytic formula, see my answer. Basically there are two infinite families of solutions and you just have to choose the ones you want in your particular angle range.

Comment: @Dror If we are talking about `[0, 2 Pi]` interval, then: for positive values of `Sin` (inputs, say `x`), you have `ArcSin[x]` and `Pi - ArcSin[x]`, while for negative values of `x` you have `Pi - ArcSin[x]` and `2 Pi + ArcSin[x]`.

Answer (score 5):

Implicit in [Leonid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994780/range-of-inverse-trigonometric-functions-in-mathematica/6995235#6995235) is the formula

```
In[1]:= Reduce[Sin[x] == y, x]
Out[1]= (x == ArcSin[y] + 2*Pi*C[1] || x == Pi - ArcSin[y] + 2*Pi*C[1]) && Element[C[1], Integers]
```

[image: the above, but nicer]

From the two above infinite families of solutions, you can find the angles satisfying `y = sin(x)` for any given `y` and range of acceptable `x` (See Leonid's answer, which, every time it's called, generates the above along with the extra condition `start <= x <= end` and spits out all solutions for `x`.)

The explicit formula for x values in the range `[0, Pi)` is

```
In[2]:= Reduce[Sin[x] == y && 0 <= x < 2 Pi, x]

Out[2]=    (y == -1 && x == (3 Pi)/2) 
        || (y == 1 &&  x == Pi/2) 
        || (-1 < y < 1 && x == Pi - ArcSin[y]) 
        || (-1 < y < 0 && x == ArcSin[y] + 2 Pi) 
        || (0 <= y < 1 && x == ArcSin[y])
```

Note that the first two lines are the edge values, the middle line is taken from one family of the above infinite solutions and the last two lines taken together are from the other family of solutions.  This agrees with Leonids comment:

> for positive values of `Sin` (inputs, say `x`), you have `ArcSin[x]` and `Pi`
>   `-ArcSin[x]`, while for negative values of `x` you have `Pi - ArcSin[x]`
>   and `2 Pi + ArcSin[x]`.

The above formulae assume the principal value for `ArcSin`.

---

### Principal Value

In any 2 pi period, there are two solutions to `Sin[x] == y` for a given `y`. This is obvious from the graph for `Sin[x]` (which is 2 pi periodic)

[image: sin(x)==y]

To have a unique inverse function [`x = ArcSin[y]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsin%28y%29) you need to choose which particular solution (out of the two infinite families) you want. Mathematica chooses the standard range `-Pi/2 < x < Pi/2`. This choice is (by convention) the principal value of the [inverse trigonometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions)

[image: inverse function]

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `ArcSin`, as you will be well aware of, is the inverse function of the `Sin` function which isn't bijective in the range [0,2 Pi]. Some of the x values in this range yield the same `Sin` value (e.g., Sin[3/4 [Pi]] == Sin[1/4 [Pi]]), so you can't reverse this process.

The closest you can get in plotting would be something like:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], x}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
   Ticks -> {Automatic, (Range[0, 8] \[Pi]/4)}]
]
```

[image]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcqxy.png">